# Send data from javascript to python in google app engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

i want to create an application in google app engine using python. I have to send a list of json string to python script.I have done the following code but ain't worked.

```
$.post("/javascriptdata",{v:s},function(data,status) {});
```

In python script i have a class named javascriptdata to where data has to be send to

```
import wsgiref.handlers
import json
import sys
import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import Request
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class mainh(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(template.render("paint.html",{}))

class javascriptdata(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['content-Type'] = 'html'
        data1=self.request.get('v')
        self.response.out.write("""<html><body>""")
        self.response.out.write(data1)
        self.response.out.write("""</body></html>""")


def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
        ('/',mainh),("/save",javascriptdata)], debug=True)
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The javascriptdata is associated with the url "/save". I have created a submit button named "save" that would redirect to /save but iam not getting any output. I know it may be a silly mistake but Iam struggling to sort it out. Please suggest me how to post and read the data for this code.

Comment: where is the jQuery code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems suspicious:

`$.post("/javascriptdata",{v:s},function(data,status) {});`

since you don't have a `/javascriptdata` URL mapped in the python code.  Perhaps you meant

`$.post('/save', ...`?

Alternatively, you could change the `WSGIApplication` init to be:

`...("/javascriptdata",javascriptdata)...`

Comment: $.post('/save', ...? is his problem I think